# jQuery UI .addClass() animation with padding in IE9+

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, addclass

I have a page on which there are several square `<div>`s, some of which, when clicked, have hidden content associated with them that needs to be displayed (let's call them "expandable divs").  The hidden content can sometimes be quite lengthy so it resides in separate `<div>`s ("detail divs").  The desired effect is for the "detail div" to first imitate the size and position of of the "expandable div" before running a jQuery UI animated `.addClass('fullscreen', 'fast', 'swing')` call which applies the following rules:

```
.detail.fullscreen {
  top: 0 !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  padding: 0 10%; /* all elements on page use box-sizing:border-box */
}
```

The `.addClass()` animation works like a charm in Chrome, Firefox, and oddly enough, even in IE8.  However, the animation does not work correctly in IE9+.  The browser seems to be unable to animate the `padding`, and just tacks the property on after the animation is complete, making for a really ugly UI bug.  Please see the jsFiddle below to see the bug in action:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xb6Pf/4/)

My best guess is that this has something to do with the way that IE renders `box-sizing: border-box;`, but this style is so useful and works perfectly fine in all other modern browsers.  Am I missing something?

NOTE: I've also noticed that jQuery 2.x and jQuery UI 1.10.x don't work for me in jsFiddle in IE, but maybe that's a question for another day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is occurring because of the difference of box modal. As you said, its because of padding only. To solve this issue remove paading from detail `<div>`and add a div inside your detail `<div>` with padding. This will give you the desired effect.